# how i can join msdb.dbo.sysoperators and msdb.dbo.sysalerts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i use sql server 2008 r2.

and i want create script of all my jobs for back up.

i need find all object that exist in one job. and now i can do this but

To achieve this goal, i most get all operators whit this query

```
Select O.* From msdb.dbo.sysoperators As O
```

and i can find all Alert whit this query

```
Select * From msdb.dbo.sysalerts
```

Each alerts have several operators.

i want join the two tables together.

how i can get all operators for all alert ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you most use of this query

```
Select * 
From sysalerts As Ale
    Inner Join sysnotifications As Noti on ( Ale.id = Noti.alert_id )
    Inner Join sysoperators As Ope On ( Noti.operator_id = ope.id )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
SELECT sa.*, so.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysalerts sa
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysnotifications sn ON sn.alert_id = sa.id
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysoperators so ON so.id = sn.operator_id
```